# How to integrate Tez payment gateway in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-tez

I want to implement google's Tez payment into my app, but as far I found that google provides api integration guide for web and android only(https://developers.google.com/tez/documentation/).

Is anyone know from where I can get documentation guide to implement Tez in my app?

If no source available, then shall we redirect our app to the Tez app in iOS  Appstore?, if this'll be the case, then how can I redirect to my app after the successful payment in Tez app.

Looking forward for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, if Google is not providing any framework to integrate the payment for iOS. Wait for the time, till the Google launch framework for iOS.

You can redirect the user to Tez App on AppStore, but it won't help, because you will not get the idea about the payment status as well as cannot redirect back to your app.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As a possibility, you can [implement Tez framework on server side](https://developers.google.com/tez/documentation/web/intro), and integrate it through your iOS app using web service (Since iOS SDK is not available). But remember to check the apple review guideline about payments through a 3rd party framework because you might have to justify them the use of it for approval.